# JavaScript or ActionScript for advertising

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm working on a little website,but i've never insert advertising in a web page, and i want to test it.So to create them,is it possible with JavaScript,or i must learn ActionScript?

Comment: You should learn JavaScript. Action script you need to use with flash and it require flash player pluggin. Nowadays everyone is going for fast and less resource.

Comment: well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I program with JavaScript,but i'm not a pro.I wanted to try yo include advertising,and with a Google research,many people are talking about ActionScript and i've never used it.So what i want to know is if it possible to do the same thing with JS

Comment: Is your question **_"how to create an advert"_**? or **_"how to insert an existing advert into HTML page"_**? Two different things so which Answer do you need? When asked _"What have you tried so far?"_ it means the reply should be : _"I tried to insert like so..."_ + links to example page + link to original advert. Then we can help you fix visible problem... Maybe your issue can be solved with some `i-frame` pointing to the advert image/video. But who knows when we can't see...

Comment: Since it's a website use javascript to embed the advert (even if ad is an SWF file). The advert provider should give you embed code to use on your web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the adverts you intend to put on your page. If you intend to generate the ads on server-side, then you will need to do that using your server-side language, which can be PHP, Java, a .NET language or even Javascript if you are using NodeJS. If you need to generate it on client-side, then Javascript is preferable. For instance AdSense ads are using Javascript. I would only choose to learn ActionScript for this purpose if there was a service I would intend to use and that service would be already using ActionScript.

Comment: So,if i want my website visitors to see the advert in the case that my website is hosted,i should only use server-side language?So,in what case,should i choose to use a server-side language or a client language?

Comment: @ChristianLisangola it is up to you, on what fits you better.